C code to sign a message compatible (such that can be verified) with Metamask, mycrypto, etc
I am on macOS and trying to put together the code to sign (and once I succeed to verify) a message with an Ethereum private key. So, the private key (just used to test, no funds there lol) is: a7f1d92a82c8d8fe434d98558ce2b347171198542f112d0558f56bd688079992 (equivalent to address: 0x16B3e66c49d0149323f7f288eB132d6fD27d0a82). The message to sign is "Hello". I ask, as I can't find anything around with a working example. I did 4 attempts, and each returns a different result, which is not the correct one:
sodium.c:   829aeae1d25975b0a4cfd7381cbb946aa18d5e90f3c9f720897de9d05a69fa121a643e86cea3a0f7b84852d0671ad8915f4852270d9e5256d9ccd77961a39909
secp.c:     c199f596190bebe8c5815e24a75bfd86234f40e2758c6c5071a96ed2da80dee842be2c853e41be7b99631140bc1de9afdb31fdee571d4c0b03ec7890f4a33e04
eth_sign.c: 1109df90bdbfde3a517f4f5d11195fcfd56c1fc8cd264d42d04f75dfe46020520c0f1cafe6f2719a543c6ad0cf3d5b61ad1749d6725b4f8f7d19e5f75db718d81b
lallo.c:    fbc28c0979da76832b39c9387fae7d9f1a295680380912e9a620311c3f78ffd30ed85e443291619b296a7c40d98e2a60e51f6d755034dbcd761e0f28945ee3fd1b
the correct signature (done with Metamask and MyCrypto) is:
{
  "address": "0x16B3e66c49d0149323f7f288eB132d6fD27d0a82",
  "msg": "Hello",
  "sig": "0x9e53d8d8e75777865a86cbb680c848da106c7b88fd540850da131d47b28c81f0665bc7c4fb06d92b927bd5cb06ffa68ca4743dfbc1ab6569c16c082cf3ecead91c",
  "version": "2"
}

Here is the code for the 4 different attempts I have made:
=====================================================================================
sodium.c:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sodium.h>

#define PRIVATE_KEY_SIZE 32
#define SIGNATURE_SIZE 64

int main() {
    // Initialize libsodium
    if (sodium_init() < 0) {
        printf("Failed to initialize libsodium\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Ethereum private key (replace with your own)
    unsigned char private_key[PRIVATE_KEY_SIZE] = {
        0xa7, 0xf1, 0xd9, 0x2a, 0x82, 0xc8, 0xd8, 
        0xfe, 0x43, 0x4d, 0x98, 0x55, 0x8c, 0xe2, 
        0xb3, 0x47, 0x17, 0x11, 0x98, 0x54, 0x2f, 
        0x11, 0x2d, 0x05, 0x58, 0xf5, 0x6b, 0xd6, 
        0x88, 0x07, 0x99, 0x92
    };

    // Message to be signed
    const char* message = "Hello";

    // Convert the message to bytes
    unsigned char* message_bytes = (unsigned char*)message;
    size_t message_len = strlen(message);

    // Allocate memory for the signature
    unsigned char signature[SIGNATURE_SIZE];

    // Sign the message
    crypto_sign_detached(signature, NULL, message_bytes, message_len, private_key);

    // Print the signature
    printf("Signature:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < SIGNATURE_SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%02x", signature[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

compiled with:
gcc sodium.c -o sodium -I/opt/homebrew/include -L/opt/homebrew/lib -lsodium
=====================================================================================
secp.c:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <secp256k1.h>
#include <secp256k1_recovery.h>

// Helper function to convert hex string to byte array.
int hex_to_bytes(unsigned char *byte_array, const char *hex_string, size_t byte_array_max_len) {
    size_t hex_len = strlen(hex_string);
    if (hex_len % 2 != 0 || byte_array_max_len < hex_len / 2) return 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < hex_len / 2; i++) {
        sscanf(hex_string + 2 * i, "%2hhx", &byte_array[i]);
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    secp256k1_context *ctx = secp256k1_context_create(SECP256K1_CONTEXT_SIGN | SECP256K1_CONTEXT_VERIFY);
    unsigned char private_key[32];
    unsigned char message_hash[32]; // The hash of your message.

    // Dummy private key and message hash (normally you would compute the hash of your message)
    hex_to_bytes(private_key, "a7f1d92a82c8d8fe434d98558ce2b347171198542f112d0558f56bd688079992", sizeof(private_key));
    hex_to_bytes(message_hash, "d2db873cf20e1c2adb055858b52ebdd31f4742804df0ec67f94f795393d06840", sizeof(message_hash));

    secp256k1_ecdsa_recoverable_signature signature;
    if (!secp256k1_ecdsa_sign_recoverable(ctx, &signature, message_hash, private_key, NULL, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to sign the message.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Serialize the signature in compact format
    unsigned char output[64];
    int recid;
    secp256k1_ecdsa_recoverable_signature_serialize_compact(ctx, output, &recid, &signature);

    printf("Signature: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        printf("%02x", output[i]);
    }
    printf("\nRecovery ID: %d\n", recid);

    secp256k1_context_destroy(ctx);
    return 0;
}

compiled with:
gcc secp.c -o secp -I/opt/homebrew/include -L/opt/homebrew/lib -lsecp256k1
=====================================================================================
eth_sign.c:
#include <ethc/keccak256.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>
#include <openssl/obj_mac.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <openssl/ecdsa.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>

void print_hex(const unsigned char *data, size_t length) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        printf("%02x", data[i]);
    }
}

void print_bn(const BIGNUM *bn) {
    char *hex = BN_bn2hex(bn);
    printf("%s", hex);
    OPENSSL_free(hex);
}

int main() {
    const unsigned char msg[] = "Hello";
    
    // Ethereum-style inner message preparation
    char eth_inner_message[256];
    snprintf(eth_inner_message, sizeof(eth_inner_message), "%s", (const char *)msg); // Corrected formatting
    size_t eth_inner_message_len = strlen(eth_inner_message); // Get length after snprintf

    unsigned char eth_inner_message_hash[32];
    eth_keccak256(eth_inner_message_hash, (unsigned char *)eth_inner_message, eth_inner_message_len);

    // Ethereum-style message preparation
    char eth_message[256];
    eth_message[0] = 0x19; // Correct hex value for initialization
    snprintf(eth_message + 1, sizeof(eth_message) - 1, "Ethereum Signed Message:\n32%s", (char *)eth_inner_message_hash);

    size_t eth_message_len = strlen(eth_message);

    unsigned char eth_message_hash[32];
    eth_keccak256(eth_message_hash, (unsigned char *)eth_message, eth_message_len);

    // Private key initialization
    const char *priv_key_hex = "a7f1d92a82c8d8fe434d98558ce2b347171198542f112d0558f56bd688079992";
    BIGNUM *priv_bn = BN_new();
    BN_hex2bn(&priv_bn, priv_key_hex);

    EC_GROUP *group = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1);
    EC_KEY *ec_key = EC_KEY_new();
    EC_KEY_set_group(ec_key, group);
    EC_KEY_set_private_key(ec_key, priv_bn);

    // Set a fixed value for 'k'
    const char *k_hex = "1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef";
    BIGNUM *k_bn = BN_new();
    BN_hex2bn(&k_bn, k_hex);

    // Create ECDSA signature
    ECDSA_SIG *signature = ECDSA_do_sign_ex(eth_message_hash, 32, k_bn, NULL, ec_key);
    if (!signature) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating ECDSA signature\n");
        return 1;
    }

    const BIGNUM *sig_r, *sig_s;
    ECDSA_SIG_get0(signature, &sig_r, &sig_s);

    unsigned char sig_eth[65];
    memset(sig_eth, 0, 65);
    BN_bn2bin(sig_r, sig_eth + 32 - BN_num_bytes(sig_r));
    BN_bn2bin(sig_s, sig_eth + 64 - BN_num_bytes(sig_s));
    sig_eth[64] = 27; // Set 'v' to 27

    printf("Message: %s\n", msg);
    printf("Message Hash: ");
    print_hex(eth_message_hash, 32);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Signature (r, s, v): ");
    print_hex(sig_eth, 65);
    printf("\n");

    // Clean up
    ECDSA_SIG_free(signature);
    BN_free(k_bn);
    EC_KEY_free(ec_key);
    BN_free(priv_bn);

    return 0;
}

compiled with:
gcc -o eth_sign eth_sign.c -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1w/include -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1w/lib -I/usr/local/include/ethc -L/usr/local/lib -I/opt/homebrew/include -lethc -lcrypto -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib
=====================================================================================
lallo.c:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <secp256k1.h>
#include <ethc/keccak256.h>
#include <secp256k1_recovery.h>

void print_hex(const unsigned char* data, size_t length) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        printf("%02x", data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    // Create context
    secp256k1_context* ctx = secp256k1_context_create(SECP256K1_CONTEXT_SIGN);

    unsigned char private_key[32] = {
        0xa7, 0xf1, 0xd9, 0x2a, 0x82, 0xc8, 0xd8, 
        0xfe, 0x43, 0x4d, 0x98, 0x55, 0x8c, 0xe2, 
        0xb3, 0x47, 0x17, 0x11, 0x98, 0x54, 0x2f, 
        0x11, 0x2d, 0x05, 0x58, 0xf5, 0x6b, 0xd6, 
        0x88, 0x07, 0x99, 0x92
    };

    // Create public key
    secp256k1_pubkey pubkey;
    int pubkey_status = secp256k1_ec_pubkey_create(ctx, &pubkey, private_key);

    if (pubkey_status != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create public key.\n");
        secp256k1_context_destroy(ctx);
        return 1; // Exit with error code
    }

    unsigned char message[32] = {0}; 
    strncpy((char *)message, "Hello", sizeof(message) - 1);

    // Hash with Keccak256
    unsigned char eth_inner_hash[32];
    eth_keccak256(eth_inner_hash, message, sizeof(message) - 1);

    // Sign message
    secp256k1_ecdsa_signature sig;
    secp256k1_ecdsa_sign(ctx, &sig, eth_inner_hash, private_key, NULL, NULL);

    // Serialize to compact form
    unsigned char signature[65];
    secp256k1_ecdsa_signature_serialize_compact(ctx, signature, &sig);

    // Add Ethereum-specific recovery ID for `v`
    signature[64] = 27; // or 28, depending on network or recovery requirement

    // Print the Ethereum-style signature in hex
    printf("Ethereum-style signature in hex: ");
    print_hex(signature, 65);

    // Destroy context at the end
    secp256k1_context_destroy(ctx);

    return 0;
}

compiled with:
gcc -o lallo lallo.c -I/opt/homebrew/include -L/opt/homebrew/lib -lsecp256k1 -lcrypto -Wl,-rpath,/opt/homebrew/lib -L/usr/local/lib -I/opt/homebrew/include -lethc
=====================================================================================
ChatGPR and Claude3 Opus both failed in helping me lol... Any of you are better than AI?

How are you generating this signature (0x9e53d8d8e75777865a86cbb680c848da106c7b88fd540850da131d47b28c81f0665bc7c4fb06d92b927bd5cb06ffa68ca4743dfbc1ab6569c16c082cf3ecead91c) using MetaMask? I mean, how did you encode the message Hello before signing? Can you share the generated hash of Hello that's being signed?

Hello @SYEDASADKAZMI, if you take Metamask, import account using the private key, and go to mycrypto.com on the sign message utility, you will get that signature. Unfortunately it doesn't show the hash of the message before signing it :( Unless it leaks in the browser, need to check.

Noted. You can also see this Javascript code, it gives the hash and the signature, and the same can be verified too.

So, it’s giving the exact hash and signature that we need to generate using the C code. But when I debugged, I can see the difference lies in generating the encodedParams using encodeABI itself.

As, in C, it’s not encoding it in the same way. Using C, getting 68656c6c6f, whereas using JS getting this:
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000568656c6c6f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Even, I tried hashing this hardcoded hex value, but the keccak256 function of C, it’s giving different hash.

So, second thing is to generate the same hash for encoded value 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000568656c6c6f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (after removing 0x).

The hashed value generated using JS code is 984002fcc0ca639f96622add24c2edd2fe72c65e71ca3faa243e091e0bc7cdab, i.e., the same as https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html?input_type=hex&input=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000568656c6c6f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.

Wow @SYEDASADKAZMI! Thank you for your analysis. I will check and hopefully I will get how to hash it properly, even if I have to write the library by myself lol... I will share here how it goes...

Sounds great. Please keep me updated. I’ll be happy to contribute, wherever required.

I believe you need to reverse the bytes into little endian. Instead of the bytes 48 65 6C 6C 6F you need to reverse the hex values like so, 6F 6C 6C 65 48
I could be wrong, the lib you're using may do that already, idk. Give it a try and mark it answered if it works out.

Can you be more specific? Not sure I understand what you mean, and where this should happen...
